# how to get access the delegate of other Class and update the data

Tags: iphone

class 1{

class1Array;

pickerview;

pickerview.datasource=self;(here class1Array)

pickerivew.delegate=self;

}

class 2{

here from how can i get the delegate of class1 pickerview and update the Class1Array.

after that while pop from class2 to class1, pickerview must show the new array ,which is from class2.

shouldnot use appdelegate

}

Comment: How exactly are you declaring your array and pickerview?  Looks strange.  Also, why not just make them instance variables and you can access them in all classes?

Comment: Is class 1 your root object? Or does the a instance variable of class 2 own an instance variable of class 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within class 1 define properties for the array as well as the picker view:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* array;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPickerView* pickerView;
```

For any instance of class 1 you can then access the array and pickerview through

```
instance = [[Class1 alloc] init];
instance.array = ...
instance.pickerview = ...
```

EDIT:

Sample of using static class variables:

```
@interface Class1 : NSObject {
}
+ (NSArray*)getArray;
@end

@implementation Class1
static NSArray* array = nil;

+ (NSArray*)getArray {
    if (! array) {
        array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Your", @"data", @"goes", @"here", nil];
    }
    return array;
}
@end
```

You can then access the array from anywhere using

```
[Class1 getArray]
```

Comment: without allocating the class1 object how can we access.that means how to get the whole object of class1 which is pushee, to class2, which is pushed by class1.

Comment: Well, you would have to declare the array and pickerview as static global variables inside class1 and add a class method to access them. I have to say, I do not fully understand your problem. Why don't you want to allocate an instance of class1?

Comment: like [[uiapplication sharedapplication]delegate] then we can get ivar of appdelegate right .like that how can i.but your second answer is very impressive please give me some code sample about that